# Is there anyway i can convert the Value data into actual column names in StructuredStreaming from Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a csv file which has columns and for the testing purpose i push it manually to Kafka and from there i read it into Spark and apply some parsing and i do a console output for testing purposes. Now i understand the csv data is streamed as Value in structured streaming for which i cast it to String. My requirement is if i can convert the value data to the actual columns. There are hundreds of columns in the csv file but i am only looking at two specific columns "SERVICE_NAME8" & "_raw"

I use spark.sql to extract these columns when i read the csv file from a path but now i use structured streaming i am not sure if i can extract these specific columns as a new dataframe and apply my parsing thereafter

```
val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "10.160.172.45:9092, 10.160.172.46:9092, 10.160.172.100:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "TOPIC_WITH_COMP_P2_R2, TOPIC_WITH_COMP_P2_R2.DIT, TOPIC_WITHOUT_COMP_P2_R2.DIT")
      .load()

    val dfs = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").toDF()

    val data =dfs.withColumn("splitted", split($"value", "/"))
      .select($"splitted".getItem(4).alias("region"),$"splitted".getItem(5).alias("service"),col("value"))
      .withColumn("service_type", regexp_extract($"service", """.*(Inbound|Outbound|Outound).*""",1))
      .withColumn("region_type", concat(
        when(col("region").isNotNull,col("region")).otherwise(lit("null")), lit(" "),
        when(col("service").isNotNull,col("service_type")).otherwise(lit("null"))))

    val extractedDF = data.filter(
      col("region").isNotNull &&
        col("service").isNotNull &&
        col("value").isNotNull &&
        col("service_type").isNotNull &&
        col("region_type").isNotNull)
      .filter("region != ''")
      .filter("service != ''")
      .filter("value != ''")
      .filter("service_type != ''")
      .filter("region_type != ''")

val query = extractedDF
.writeStream
.format("console")
.outputMode("append")
.trigger(ProcessingTime("20 seconds"))
.start()
```

After val dfs = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").toDF() i somehow need to extract only two columns "SERVICE_NAME8" & "_raw" and parsing should do the rest and produce output

Comment: Any reason for downvoting i am just trying to understand

Comment: I upvoted you, probably for not reading manual.

Answer (score 0):

In [Spark structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example) quick example you could see that
  `df.as[String].map(_.split("/"))` 
should transform stream to same `data` as you have in spark.sql code.
Next you could extract only desired columns and process it. For example
`data.map(line=>(line[SERVICE_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX], line[RAW_COLUMN_INDEX]))`
will get `Tuple` of two columns for each line.
Please note it's just example. I don't run it. Also I suppose `Tuple` is not the best solution.